# Android Firebase UI, PhoneAuth remove unnecessary countries from spinner dialog

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Is there a way to remove unnecessary countries from spinner dialog in PhoneAuth activity. There are so many countries but my app is only functional in india, I just want India's code (+91).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is supported. This looks like a good feature request. You should file one for it. Right now, you can only select a default country code but you can't remove countries from the selector.

Comment: Download the source from github and edit as I want, problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

this is possible. Here is my working code...

```
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> idpConfigs = new ArrayList<>();
    idpConfigs.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder()
            .setWhitelistedCountries(Collections.singletonList("IN"))
    );

    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                    .setAvailableProviders(idpConfigs)
                    .build()
            , RC_SIGN_IN
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(EXTRA_DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE, "IQ");

IdpConfig phoneConfigWithDefaultNumber =
      new IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER)
              .setParams(params)
              .build();
```

Can you try this?

Comment: I think that is depreciated, and we can do that by calling PhoneBuilder().setDefaultCountryIso(). but that's not what I want. I want to remove unnecessary countries from the list